# Border for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to create a border above the grid(named as Holder) for wp7? What i tried is, when i create the grid to full screen and after i created the border on the top of the screen but when i debug it, the border is not visible. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

```
<Grid x:Name="BrowserHost" GotFocus="BrowserHost_GotFocus" Grid.RowSpan="2">

<StackPanel x:Name="Stack" Background="Transparent">
        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
            <TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox" KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" Background="White" Margin="0,0,98,0">
        </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const int NumTabs = 4;

    private int currentIndex;
    private string[] urls = new string[NumTabs];
    private WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[NumTabs];

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowTab(0);
    }

    private void ShowTab(int index)
    {
        this.currentIndex = index;
        UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "";
        if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null) 
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser;
            BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++) 
        {
            if (this.browsers[i] != null) 
            {
            this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}

private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter) 
    {
        Uri url;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url)) 
        {
            this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
            this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid url");
    }
}
```

But after i debug, neither the border nor UrlTextBox is visible.  
Image:  
[image: Here's an image I wanted to post]

I used the GotFocus event for the BrowserHost grid. That means, when i touched the grid(BrowserHost), the UrlTextBox and the border should be collapsed(I got this thing). And what i need is the BrowserHost should attain the full screen after the Border and UrlTextBox is collapsed. But for me it is not happening. Please see the below image. I want to make the BrowserHost in full screen when the user touches on the BrowserHost. I want the empty space to be filled with BrowserHost.

[image]

Comment: You may have to specify a size for the border, otherwise it may be implementing with a width of 0 (and therefore be invisible)

Comment: Do you have any samples that deals with border?

Comment: your border line should read `<Border x:Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" >`

Comment: @matt5784 Am very sorry, i forgot say one thing. Actualy i have created a web browser control through codes(in xaml.cs) on the BrowserHost. I think that's why the border is still not visible for me. Can you help me with?

Comment: Do you want the border around the web browser control, the browser host, the stackpanel? What are you trying to do here? More explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @matt5784 Now i have edited my above post, please check it. But due to less reputation am not able to show images.

Comment: @matt5784 I have edited my post again with another image. PLease see that, the border and UrlTextBox is working good but the BrowserHost is not able to attain the full screen when it GotFocus. I want the empty space to be filled with BrowserHost. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties for the Border, like this

```
<Border Background="LightBlue" 
    BorderBrush="Green" 
    BorderThickness="2" >
```

Update:
Also Set Grid.Row="0" to your stackpanel.

And then modify your cs code

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Height = 400;
Grid.SetRow(browser, 1);
BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
```

Comment: That didnt work! Do you have any samples that deals with border?

Comment: <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Stack" Background="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Background="White" Margin="0,0,98,0"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
</Grid>
I tested this code, and its working fine for me(showing the border for the TextBox

Comment: Using a `BorderBrush` of Black on the default color scheme of a WP7 app will essentially be invisible. Change the color and the border will appear.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Yeah I figured it and so changed it in the above comment

Comment: @nkchandra Am very sorry, i forgot say one thing. Actualy i have created a web browser control through codes(in xaml.cs) on the BrowserHost. I think that's why the border is still not visible for me. Can you help me with?

Comment: @user1414139 sure, edit your question with that info and your xaml.cs code

Comment: @nkchandra Now i have edited my above post, please check it. But due to less reputation am not able to show images.

Comment: @user1414139 I have edited my answer, check it now
Dont forget to add, BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties to Border

Comment: @nkchandra I have edited my post again with another image. PLease see that, the border and UrlTextBox is working good but the BrowserHost is not able to attain the full screen when it GotFocus. I want the empty space to be filled with BrowserHost. Need help!